# Google search results say "No information available for the page" instead of the meta description or a snippet

Tags: seo, google, google-search, wordpress

I have a WordPress website and I am using the Yoast SEO plugin for its SEO. I have added my site to the Google Search Console too.

Something strange has happened recently: Google showed the site's meta description for some time, but until recently, it's showing nothing. 
 Instead it says "No information available for the page". The problem is my site does show up in search results for my preferred keyword, but Google has suddenly decided to not show any description for the page.

Answer (score 1):

Wasi, google is testing lots of things in recent. Like omitting commas from search meta description etc. All this are happening from Google. Wait for sometime, It will back. That surely bug from their end.

And as you have mentioned about Yoast plugin, Keep it updated and try a test page in wordpress without Yoast, where you manually put HTML Meta tags, if such error happening. We have seen cases where such description are omitting due to yoast plugin.

Comment: Thanks Vijay. I noticed something else too today: Google is showing a description for some keywords while not for others. Of particular interest to me is the fact that it is not showing it for the main keyword that we are using and that we have used in our meta description too, isn't that funny? Any ideas on why this is happening?